# Which parser to use?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I've got an application in which I would like to connect to the server where I'll get some xml file whish I will parse later. So the first question, as I know, there are exist three type of the parsers: `XmlPullParse` , `DOMParser` and `SAXParser`. Which of them I should use? Which is the most convinient?
And the second question is - how should I store my xml file? Should I download it and store in res/assets folder or should save it on my sdcard, or, maybe, I should parse it directly from server?
If it possible, give me an answer with some links with examles.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Which parser you used depends on your requirements. 2. You can't store anything in assets at run-time. 3. There are quite a few examples online. If you can't find them, www.google.com might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is domain object model.  It parses the entire file, then allows you to query for elements in it.  SAX is a streaming parser.  It allows you to stream an xml file, but requires you to handle each tag/item as it reads it.  DOM requires more memory and has a high initial overhead.  SAX is harder to work with and requires you to totally parse it at the time it reads the file.  Use the one better for your application.  XmlPullParse is a form of a SAX parser.